# Does a blueshift change the energy of a photon?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, photons, wave-particle-duality

The energy of a photon depends on its wavelength, so theoretically when it is blueshifted it should have more energy right?

Then what if a spaceship with a solar panel on the front is traveling towards the sun at relativistic speeds. An incoming photon undergoes a blueshift from the observer on the spacecraft. So does the solar panel read the same energy as if the light wasn't blueshifted? I see two options here: 1. Either the solar panel reads two different numbers depending on the observer. (almost like 2 realities exist) 
2. Or it reads the same because the energy of the photon is not actually based on wavelength

To keep it simple let's imagine we're only talking about one photon, because time dilation might affect the power level the solar panel was reading.

Comment: I just want to point out that the relativity of energy is not limited to special (or general) relativity. The kinetic energy of a moving object depends on the reference frame even in Newtonian mechanics. It shouldn't be surprising that such a thing occurs for light in relativistic mechanics. In fact, conservation of energy in matter/light interactions dictates that a photons energy must depend on reference frame since the matter's kinetic energy does.

Comment: @josh314 The question here is not why the energy is different in different frames. This is obvious. The question is why the energy measured by the panel is the same in both frames. (1) In the ship frame the panel is stationary, the photons are blueshifted. (2) In the Earth frame the panel is moving (it is in the ship), the photons are not blueshifted. In the Earth frame, why does a moving panel register a blueshifted energy of the non-blueshifted photons? The speed of light is the same in all frames. Neither of the 3 answers so far actually answer the question.

Comment: "the solar panel reads two different numbers depending on the observer" There's only one "observer" of the photon. Observers of the solar panel aren't measuring the photon themselves.

Comment: @safesphere If you work in the panel's rest frame, the photons are blueshifted.  If you work in some other observer's frame, the panel is moving, which shifts its absorption frequencies. Either way the actual numbers come out the same in the end.  It might help to read up on how [Doppler cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_cooling) works, as this is an effect which directly depends on atoms "observing" shifted wavelengths of light depending on their own motion.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d4/Velocity0_70c.jpg/220px-Velocity0_70c.jpg

Answer (score 15):

The energy of a photon is related to its frequency or wavelength. However the energy is a conserved quantity in a specific reference frame, but it is not an invariant. Another reference frame in relative motion vs. the former measures a different energy.

In the example the observer on the spaceship approaching the sun experiences the blueshift of the solar photons. The solar panel on the spaceship reads a higher energy of the solar radiation.

Comment: While energy is not invariant, the device reading is invariant and does not depend on the observer.

Comment: @safesphere. The 4-momentum is a conserved quantity, while the norm or the square of the 4-momentum is an invariant. As energy is a component of the 4-momentum, it is conserved, but not an invariant. Same consideration as for the 3-momentum.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was not clear. If a device is used that measures energy and this device shows a particular value measured, this value would be invariant and the same in any reference frame despite the fact that the energy is different in different frames. Your answer seems to contradict this. (May be it doesn't, but it seems to.) I believe the OP question is to explain the spaceship device reading high energy in the frame of the observer on the Earth where the photons are not blueshifted. Your answer does not explain it.

Comment: @safesphere: can you clarify the difference between a device recording the energy of the photon and an observer? My understanding is that an observer is the thing recording the value which in this case would be the device...

Comment: @Chris I believe the OP question is to explain in the frame of the Earth why a moving solar panel records a different photon energy than a stationary panel. This would be easy to explain for massive particles instead of photons by the relative speed. Not so obvious for massless photons, so a very good question that for some reason is apparently misunderstood.

Comment: Ah. My interpretation of the OP's question is that they are considering two frames, one "stationary" on earth, and the other flying towards the sun with some speed. Then they are asking if an identical solar panel in each frame measures the same or different results.

Comment: @Chris No, that would be trivial and uninteresting. He clearly asks if the panel reads two different numbers ("different realities"), so obviously the same panel. And 9 upvotes so far for a bad answer? Wow! Is this a physics site or popularity contest? ;)

Comment: @safesphere. The number on the display of the solar panel shows what is measured in that specific reference frame. It is like a ruler on the spaceship which is a unit length, but in another frame that length is measured contracted.

Comment: @MicheleGrosso Let's simplify the setup. Imagine a fan with light detectors mounted on the blades and a light source positioned in such a way that the detectors move toward the light when the fan rotates. The energy measured will depend on the speed of the fan. Are you seriously suggesting that this only can be explained in the frame of a rotating blade? Obviously not. Clearly this can be explained in the lab frame.

Comment: @safesphere is right. An observer may die because of very stiff violet radiation, it is absolute effect, it doesn't depend on chosen frame. This observer cannot be dead in his own frame and in the meantime alive in any other.

Comment: @Albert Thank you Albert! Finally someone with a reason on this forum :)

Comment: In relativity it is very easy to confuse absolute and relative effects. Space and time coordinates of event are frame dependent. The event itself (the observer dies) is the same in all frames. Amount of energy is conserved and belongs to the whole system - two observers and photon that bounces back and forth. , If they recede photon redshifts at each turn, if they approach each other it blueshifts.

Comment: @safesphere It would be great if you could provide your own answer to the question!

Comment: @Albert. How can an observer be in two different frames? If an observer is in a reference frame A approaching a radiation source he/she experiences a higher radiation frequency. Following your deadly example, if the measured frequency is lethal the observer dies. Another observer in a reference frame B at rest with the source experiences the solar radiation and survives.  But they are two different observers.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, blueshift increases the energy the observer receives from the photon. An analogue would be a ball thrown at a moving car - the hit will be much harder when the car is moving towards the ball than when the car is moving away from the ball.

The second part of your question can be read in two ways:

> I see two options here: 1. Either the solar panel reads two different numbers depending on the observer. (almost like 2 realities exist) 2. Or it reads the same because the energy of the photon is not actually based on wavelength.

Interpretations:

1. *"Do different human observers get different readings from the same solar panel?"* **No.** There are no quantum effects here. Only thing that matters is the velocity of the solar panel relative to the photon.
2. *"Does moving solar panel get a different reading than a stationary solar panel?"* **Yes.** The photon will give more energy to the solar panel that is moving towards it, because of blueshift.

Comment: Your interpretation 2 is not justified (not incorrect, but unsupported), because there is no blueshift in the frame of the Earth. Your analogy of a massless photon with a massive ball also does not hold. The energy of the ball is defined by the relative speed. The energy of the photon is defined by its frequency and again, the photon is not blueshifted in the frame of the Earth. Your answer does not explain the higher energy registered by a moving panel in the frame of the Earth.

Comment: The extra energy should be accounted for by the loss of kinetic energy.

Comment: @safesphere I don't quite follow you. By "frame of earth", do you mean the frame of the source emitting the photon? Also you can interpret "moving panel" as moving relative to the source of the photon (though situation gets more complex if the source is accelerating) - and in that case, I can't see how there could be a "moving panel in the frame of the Earth". A moving panel is by definition not in the same frame as the source of the photon.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Energy depends on frequency. An observer on earth and an observer on a relativistic spaceship moving towards the sun will see different frequencies due to the Doppler shift. This means the different observers will record different energies for the photons coming from the sun.

While it is a bit surprising that the relative velocity between the source of light and an observer of that light changes the observed frequency, this does not lead to the conclusion that there are "two realities".

Incidentally this doppler change in energy is leveraged in [Doppler Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_cooling) to laser cool atoms to $\mu K$ temperatures. The idea is that a laser is shot at atoms which is red detuned from the atomic transition wavelength (not resonant). If an atom is moving towards the source of the laser beam it will see that laser as being in resonance and thus will absorb the photon. This absorption will cause the atom to slow down a little bit. In contrast, if the atom is travelling the opposite direction it will see that beam red shifted even further so it is even less likely to absorb the photon. By pointing laser beams in towards the atom at all directions the atom can be slowed down because no matter which way it moves it is moving towards a beam so it always slows down.

Of course you can't use this to cool an atom indefinitely because eventually other heating effects take over and a final temperature is achieved as a balance of laser cooling and these heating effects.

Answer (score 1):

What the previous answer didn't state (at least not obviously):

> **Yes.**

$E = h \nu$ remains true whatever happens.